# What is represented by the set of complex numbers z satisfying the equation $(3+7i)z+(10-2i)\bar{z}+100=0$?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, plane-geometry

I have an objective type question :-
 The set complex numbers $z$ satisfying the equation:-
$$(3+7i)z+(10-2i)\bar{z}+100=0$$
represents:- 
A) A straight line
B) A pair of intersecting straight lines
C) A point 
D) A pair of distinct parallel straight lines
My approach:-
I have put $z=x+iy$ and solved equation to get :-
$$13x-9y+i(5x-7y)+100=0$$
i.e.
$$y=\frac{13}{9}x+\frac{100}{9}\tag{1.}$$&
$$y=\frac{5}{7}x\tag{2.}$$
So eq. $1$ & $ 2$ are two straight lines which are intersecting each other.So my answer is B)
Now i want to ask that ,is my approach and answer correct? if yes ,then is there any simpler approach? and if no then how would i get the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations are fine, but not the conclusion. You say yourself that the equations determine a point (at the intersection of the two lines). So the correct answer is C.

Comment: Can you please give one example of equation where it represents pair of straight lines?,so that i can clear out my confusions.Thanx in advance

Comment: Anything that leads to $(ax-by)+i(ax-by)+c=0$ with $c\ne0$.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get to the step where you have the equations of the two lines, there is still more work to do.  Or there would be if you had to actually find the point of intersection.  But the answer is C, not B.  Everything you've done up to that point is correct and I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it.

So why is the answer C and not B?  You started with the given equation:
$$(3+7i)z + (10-2i)\overline{z} + 100 = 0$$
Then you let $z = x+iy$:
$$(3+7i)(x+iy) + (10-2i)(x-iy) + 100 = 0$$
Then you did some algebra and ended up with:
$$13x - 9y + i(5x-7y) + 100 = 0 \tag{*}$$
Then you equated real and imaginary parts to obtain two equations, and the key here is that **both equations must be true at the same time** in order for equation (*) above to hold.  And this only happens at the point of intersection.

Comment: " both equations must be true at the same time in order for equation (*) above to hold. And this only happens at the point of intersection" I didn't quite got you there, do you mean for both equation to be true they must intersect and this equation is equation of point of intersection?

Comment: @ItiShree, we want to know when equation $(*)$ is true. If we equate real parts and imaginary parts of both sides of $(*)$ then we get $13x-9y+100=0$ and $5x-7y=0$. These two equations must both be true at the same time in order for $(*)$ to be true. Since these two equations are just equations of lines, then these two equations are both true only at the point of intersection of the lines.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying ^_^

Comment: Your answer is really great.. then by this logic, when do we have 'a pair of intersecting straight lines?' I mean, we will have two parallel straight lines if the slope of both the equations are same.. and if they are not, then we get a point (their point of intersection) as our answer. So can you give me an example where our answer would be a pair of intersecting straight lines?